# Get index of object that contains value in a nested array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I've been searching for something to help me on this particular problem but I've not found a suitable solution which works for my case. I'd really appreciate it if somebody could point me in the right direction.

I have an array:

```
var ruizTreeData = [


   {
      "Name": "Ruiz Hernandez",
      "parent": "null",
      "nodetype": "person",
      "Country": "assets/img/aml-flag-1.png",
      "children": [
        {
          "Name": "Checking",
          "nodetype": "account",
          "Country": "assets/img/aml-flag-1.png",
          "children": [
            {
              "Name": "Renato Godoy",
              "nodetype": "person",
              "Country": "assets/img/aml-flag-4.png"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Juan Nieto",
              "nodetype": "person",
              "Country": "assets/img/aml-flag-4.png"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Bani Cortes",
              "nodetype": "person",
              "Country": "assets/img/aml-flag-2.png"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Medina Marquez",
              "nodetype": "person",
              "Country": "assets/img/aml-flag-2.png"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

I have another function which is creating an object, and what I'd like to do is insert that object into this "tree" at a particular index. So for example, the user would choose to insert a new person underneath "Ruiz Hernandez", so I'd create an object which would be a sibling of "Checking". But I want it to be flexible enough so that if somebody added as a child of "Checking" we'd do the same, or a child of "Bani Cortes" we'd do the same etc.

I'm thinking I'd have to iterate `ruizTreeData` until I found "Ruiz Hernandez" and then insert the object into the `children` array of "Ruiz Hernandez".

So the array would then look like:

```
var ruizTreeData = [


   {
      "Name": "Ruiz Hernandez",
      "parent": "null",
      "nodetype": "person",
      "Country": "assets/img/aml-flag-1.png",
      "children": [
        {
          "Name": "Checking",
          "nodetype": "account",
          "Country": "assets/img/aml-flag-1.png",
          "children": [
            {
              "Name": "Renato Godoy",
              "nodetype": "person",
              "Country": "assets/img/aml-flag-4.png"
            }...
          ]
        },
        {
          "Name": "Inserted object",
          "nodetype": "account",
          "Country": "assets/img/aml-flag-1.png"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

I've tried a bunch of things, the closest I've got is:

```
positionInTree = ruizTreeData
                          .map(function (element) {return element["Name"];})
                          .indexOf("Ruiz Hernandez");
```

But this only returns at the first index, it doesn't go into the nested objects. Would I need a `for` loop for this?

I'd really appreciate some help with this. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go. You can select your element by a key/value identifier and this function will create a children property if there isn't one already with your object inside it or add your object into the already existing children property.

I added a person named Ruiz Hernandez into the last node (Checking's children) to show you how the function add your object in every node with your key/value identifier.

```js
var ruizTreeData = [
   {
      "Name": "Ruiz Hernandez",
      "parent": "null",
      "nodetype": "person",
      "Country": "assets/img/aml-flag-1.png",
      "children": [
        {
          "Name": "Checking",
          "nodetype": "account",
          "Country": "assets/img/aml-flag-1.png",
          "children": [
            {
              "Name": "Renato Godoy",
              "nodetype": "person",
              "Country": "assets/img/aml-flag-4.png"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Juan Nieto",
              "nodetype": "person",
              "Country": "assets/img/aml-flag-4.png"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Bani Cortes",
              "nodetype": "person",
              "Country": "assets/img/aml-flag-2.png"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Ruiz Hernandez",
              "nodetype": "person",
              "Country": "assets/img/aml-flag-2.png"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Medina Marquez",
              "nodetype": "person",
              "Country": "assets/img/aml-flag-2.png"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  
  Array.prototype.addChild = function(key, value, object){
    let el;
    if(this.find(x => x[key] == value)){
      this.filter(x => x[key] == value).forEach(y => y.children = (y.children) ? [...y.children, {...object}] : [{...object}])
    }
    this.forEach(y => {
        if(y.children){
          y.children.addChild(key, value, object);
        }
      });
  }
  
  ruizTreeData.addChild("Name", "Ruiz Hernandez", {Name: "Name"});
  console.log(ruizTreeData);
```

Comment: That is great. Thanks very much, you've been a big help.